# Unable to make requests.packages.urllib3 work

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib3

I am having an issue trying to use requests.packages.urllib3.exception, but i keep getting "could not be resolved".

It used to work on another project, but i tried to merge this project with a PySide6 project and it wont work anymore.

The code is from this Module: https://github.com/unistra/python-glpi-api

I tried deleting python, all the venv and reinstalling python + the modules and nothing works.
I am a novice python programmer, so my knowledge is quite limited.

thank you very much in advance !

[image: Code]

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).  It will be more readable and easier to use in answer, and more people will see it - so more people can help you.

Comment: this is NOT error in code but only warning from IDE because it can't find some information  (probably to check syntax, etc) but it has nothing to do with your code. Run code to see if it works.

Comment: @furas The code was in the github link. (im trying to use the actual module but i get the message in the screenshot)

Also, the api i was using is down atm so i cant try the software tonight.
I think i might have fixed doing this :

`import urllib3`
and replaced the line that gave me the issue with:
`from urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning`

I will keep this thread updated when i can try it with the actual api tomorrow.

Comment: it is NOT problem with your code but problem inside `IDE`. IDE has problem to find some information and using `import urllib3` in your code may not change it. Stop bother this message and simply run code.

Comment: My last comment fixed my issue.

Comment: did you try to run code without IDE and without `import ulrlib3`? I think it should run without any problems. As for me all this is only inner problem in IDE - it can't find information to test code with `Pylance` - and your code doesn't need `import urllib3` to work :) and it doesn't need to reinstall python and modules. It would rather need to  ask IDE's authors to fix this problem inside IDE. And eventually it may need to turn off `Pylance` in IDE to stop displaying this message (or maybe IDE has special type of codes to skip this line in tests).

Answer (score 2):

I added the import at the top with `import urllib3`
and replaced the line that gave me the issue with:
`from urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning`

Comment: Apart from telling the solution, it would be great if you could tell why this solution works and whether this is the correct way of doing things or if this is just a hack to the problem you are facing.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Here's a comment in the typeshed repo that explains why importing directly from `urllib3` is beneficial for typing and dependency finding: https://github.com/python/typeshed/issues/6893#issuecomment-1010246839